# boost logger doesn't rotate at midnight

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

```
logging::wsettings settings;
settings["Core"]["Filter"] = L"%Severity% >= " + level;
settings["Core"]["DisableLogging"] = false;
settings["Sinks.File"]["Destination"] = L"TextFile";
settings["Sinks.File"]["FileName"] = fileName;
settings["Sinks.File"]["Format"] = L"%TimeStamp% %Severity(format=\"%-7s\")% - %Message%";
settings["Sinks.File"]["AutoFlush"] = true;
settings["Sinks.File"]["TimeBasedRotation"] = L"00:00:00";
settings["Sinks.File"]["RotationSize"] = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
settings["Sinks.File"]["Target"] = filePath;
settings["Sinks.File"]["ScanForFiles"] = L"All";
settings["Sinks.File"]["Append"] = true;

auto previousLocale = std::locale::global(boost::locale::generator()(Constants::LOCALE));
logging::init_from_settings(settings);
logging::add_common_attributes();
```

I can see logs on different days in same log file 'App_2017-05-31.0.log'

```
2017-05-31 20:07:29.115231 info    -
2017-05-31 20:07:29.115231 info    -  
2017-06-01 01:38:45.139742 error   -  
2017-06-01 03:01:42.303604 error   -  
2017-06-01 19:56:59.995196 info    -  
2017-06-01 19:57:00.385923 info    -  
2017-06-02 01:37:05.281702 error   -  
2017-06-02 02:52:08.488442 error   -
```

Do you know how to config logger properly, so it can rotate log files at midnight, and won't have logs on different days in same log file.

Comment: Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `TimeBasedRotation` parameter. You can set either periodic rotation by setting `RotationInterval` to the number of seconds between rotations, or `RotationTimePoint` to the time point at which the rotation happens. The parameters are documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.settings).